# PHP button color change on select - without JavaScript

Tags: html, css

I have a PHP web page with 4 independent sets of buttons. I want to change to color of the button that is pressed to yellow, and for it to stay this way (even if the page is refreshed) until another button is pressed. I am trying to avoid Java if at all possible, to keep it simple for me to change later.

Here is a small code snippet:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">

body {
font: 100% Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background: #666666;
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
color: #000000;
}

.newStyle1 {
float: left; 
}

.auto-style1 {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 20px;
}

</style>
<title>Audio Control</title>
</head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<body>

<form action="" method="post" >


<fieldset style="display:inline; border:none; padding:0px; margin:0px; vertical-align:top; class="newStyle1" style="height: 450px" >
  <legend align="center"; class="auto-style1">Backyard Audio</legend>
  <br/>
  <button name="input" style="height: 1.8em; width: 10em; font-size: 16px;" value="CL2I1O1T" type="submit">Computer</button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <button name="input" style="height: 1.8em; width: 10em; font-size: 16px;" value="CL2I2O1T" type="submit">Tuner</button>
  <br />
  <br />


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean to avoid using JavaScript? You wouldn't typically use Java for this.

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible without a little bit of Javascript. To persist the data, you'd either have to send a JavaScript AJAX call to your server-side script when you click the button, or write some data to localstorage, cookies, etc. This all still requires the use of Javascript. HTML and CSS alone cannot persist data.

Comment: I am very new at PHP, but is there a way to use PHP to store the button press as a variable, and then have each button check that variable to see what color it should be?

Comment: If it's ok to do a submit/refresh of each page, then you could store the posted form-elements into session-variables.

Comment: Would it be possible to have a graphic next to the button that would change when the corresponding button is pressed? I am thinking that each HTML "status" graphic would be displayed based on whether the variable is set or not. Is that feasible?